# ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$4 cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.StreamInitiation while transfering a file

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, smack

I am using Smack and Openfire server for a chat client, all things working well like chat, sending an invitation for a new addition of user, getting list of available users etc. I encountered an error of ClassCastException when I try to send a file from a android client to another user using below code it gives me stack of error.

```
ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
if (sdm == null)
sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
fileTransfer(fileName, recepient.getText().toString() + "/Spark 2.6.3");

public void fileTransfer(String fileName, String destination) throws XMPPException   {

        FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection,true);
        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(destination);
        transfer.sendFile(new File(fileName), "You won't believe this!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Exception " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        System.out.println("Status :: " + transfer.getStatus() + " Error :: " + transfer.getError() + " Exception :: " + transfer.getException());
        System.out.println("Is it done? " + transfer.isDone());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Status :: " + transfer.getStatus() + " Error :: " + transfer.getError() + " Exception :: " + transfer.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("ONMESSAGE", "Status :: " + transfer.getStatus() + " Error :: " + transfer.getError() + " Exception :: " + transfer.getException());
    }
```

When I try to send the file, it shows up at the other end's spark however when clicked on "Accept", does not start the file transfer, instead it shows "Error in transfering file".

In Error log it shows me the below error:

```
07-25 12:08:22.393: E/AndroidRuntime(27708): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$4 cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.StreamInitiation
07-25 12:08:22.393: E/AndroidRuntime(27708):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferNegotiator.negotiateOutgoingTransfer(FileTransferNegotiator.java:401)
07-25 12:08:22.393: E/AndroidRuntime(27708):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:300)
07-25 12:08:22.393: E/AndroidRuntime(27708):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer.access$100(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:35)
07-25 12:08:22.393: E/AndroidRuntime(27708):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer$2.run(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:214)
07-25 12:08:22.393: E/AndroidRuntime(27708):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

N.B.: I am using Smack Library.

Comment: Why do you sleep your thread ?

Comment: never mind I found the answer..actually somewhere I read the thread before, just research it and found the answer. I am posting the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method to your class.

```
public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {   

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private",

            new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());

    try {

        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time",

                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        Log.w("TestClient",

                "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");

    }
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster",

            new RosterExchangeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event",

            new MessageEventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active",

            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",

            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing",

            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",

            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused",

            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",

            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive",

            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",

            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone",

            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",

            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im",

            new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference",

            new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
            new DiscoverItemsProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",

            new DiscoverInfoProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user",
            new MUCUserProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin",
            new MUCAdminProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner",
            new MUCOwnerProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",
            new DelayInformationProvider());
    try {

        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version",

                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        // Not sure what's happening here.

    }
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",

            new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup","http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup",new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses","http://jabber.org/protocol/address",new MultipleAddressesProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());

}
```

And just before connect function is called. call the method with like this.

```
configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
```

Comment: Manually configuring the ProviderManager is not necessary with the latest versions of (a)Smack. It's a sign that you either use an old aSmack version or that you didn't follow the instructions in the README if you need to do so.

Comment: @Flow May be that is the case...it is a useful information too for this post....Actually a year ago I made this client without file transfer and now I want to configure it for the file transfer thats why could not be able to change to latest library....I will change that too...Thank you for this valuable info